# Toggle active class on child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a bit of a head ache trying to figure out the React way of implementing this.

I have a Searches component which houses SearchItems, when an item is clicked among other things I need to set it's state to active to that it gets the correct CSS, I managed to get this working fine but how would I go about removing the active state from the others?

I was thinking that I could pass down a function from the top level component that would take the ID of the search, when clicked it'd zip through SearchItems and change their state to either true/false depending on which ID it was?

Code below!

Top level component:

```
    import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router";

import Search from "./Search";

    export default class Searches extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          searches : [
          {
            id : "2178348216",
            searchName: "searchName1",
            matches: "5"

          },
          {
            id : "10293840132",
            searchName: "searchName2",
            matches: "20"

          }

          ]
        };

      }

      render() {
        const { searches } = this.state;

        const SearchItems = searches.map((search) => {
          return <Search key={search.id} {...search}/>

        })

        return (
         <div> {SearchItems} </div>
          );

      }
    }
```

**Search items component**

```
export default class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Set the default panel style

    this.state = {
      panelStyle: { height: '90px', marginBottom: '6px', boxShadow: '' },
      selected: false
    }



  }

  isActive(){
    return 'row panel panel-success ' + (this.state.selected ? 'active' : 'default');
  }

viewNotifications(e){
  this.setState({selected: true});

}
    render() {
      const { id, searchName, matches } = this.props;



      const buttonStyle = {
        height: '100%',
        width: '93px',
        backgroundColor: '#FFC600'
      }

    return (
     <div style={this.state.panelStyle} className={this.isActive()}>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
       <div class="col-xs-7">
         Search Name: {searchName}
       </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
         Must Have: PHP, MySQL
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-7">
         Could Have: AngularJS
       </div>

       </div>

          <button type="button" onClick={this.viewNotifications.bind(this)} style={buttonStyle} class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> {matches} </button>



     </div>



    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need the state in the child component at all. In fact is a good idea to avoid having state in most components so they are easy to reason and reuse.

I would leave all the state only on the parent component in this case.

#### TOP Component:

```
import React from "react";

import Search from "./search";

export default class Searches extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      searches : [
        {
          id : "2178348216",
          searchName: "searchName1",
          matches: "5"
        },
        {
          id : "10293840132",
          searchName: "searchName2",
          matches: "20"
        }
      ],
      activeElement : null
    };
  }

  _onSearchSelect(searchId) {
    this.setState({'activeElement': searchId})
  }

  render() {
    const { searches, activeSearchId } = this.state;

    const SearchItems = searches.map((search) => {
      return <Search key={search.id} {...search}
        isActive={search.id === activeElement}
        onSelect={this._onSearchSelect.bind(this)} />
    })

    return (
     <div> {SearchItems} </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### CHILD Component:

```
import React from "react";

export default class Search extends React.Component {
  _getPanelClassNames() {
    const { isActive } = this.props
    return 'row panel panel-success ' + (isActive ? 'active' : 'default')
  }

  _onSelect() {
    const { id, onSelect } = this.props;
    onSelect(id)
  }

  render() {
    const { searchName, matches } = this.props;
    const panelStyle = { height: '90px', marginBottom: '6px', boxShadow: '' }
    const buttonStyle = {
      height: '100%',
      width: '93px',
      backgroundColor: '#FFC600'
    }
    return (
      <div style={panelStyle} className={this._getPanelClassNames()}>
        <div className="col-xs-4">
          Search Name: {searchName}
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-3">
          Must Have: PHP, MySQL
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-3">
         Could Have: AngularJS
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-2">
          <button type="button" onClick={this._onSelect.bind(this)}
            style={buttonStyle} className="btn btn-default btn-lg"
          >
            {matches}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can also see it running in Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/sdWzFedsdFx4MpbOuPJD?p=preview

Comment: Ohhh that's a good point, since State in the top level updates the props, what a douche - saying that I only started yesterday so these things will happen, thanks!

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself! Yes, these things happen, and not only at the beginning. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Oh fyi I just stuck a routing question up if you're feeling energetic ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out this is simpler than I thought and is simply a case of understanding how react works(and not getting confused) .

When you have a top level component you pass it's state via props to children, when you update the state in the top level component it'll pass that down to the children and you can use componentWillReceiveProps to take action.

I added a function to my top level component called updateActiveSearch which simply sets the state of the TOP level component I then passed the activeElement state as a prop to the child Elements along with the function. When a child element calls this function to set itself as active all of them will fire componentWillReceiveProps, they simply just need to check their own ID against the one they've received, if it matches they're active, if it doesn't they're not!

So my top level component now looks like this:

```
export default class Searches extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      searches : [
      {
        id : "2178348216",
        searchName: "searchName1",
        matches: "5"

      },
      {
        id : "10293840132",
        searchName: "searchName2",
        matches: "20"

      }

      ],
      activeElement : 0
    };


  }
// This function gets passed via a prop below
  updateActiveSearch(id){
    //console.log(id);
    this.setState({activeElement : id});
  }

  render() {


    const SearchItems = this.state.searches.map((search) => {
      return <Search activeElement={this.state.activeElement} goFunction={this.updateActiveSearch.bind(this)} key={search.id} {...search}/>

    })

    return (
     <div> {SearchItems} </div>
      );

  }
}
```

**CHILD COMPONENTS**

```
export default class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Set the default panel style

    this.state = {
      panelStyle: { height: '90px', marginBottom: '6px', boxShadow: '' },
      selected: false
    }

  }


// This happens right before the props get updated!   
    componentWillReceiveProps(incomingProps){
      if(incomingProps.activeElement == this.props.id){
        this.setState({selected: true});
      } else {
        this.setState({selected: false});
      }
}

  isActive(){
    return 'row panel panel-success ' + (this.state.selected ? 'active' : 'default');
  }

viewNotifications(e){
  //this.state.panelStyle.boxShadow = '-2px 3px 20px 5px rgba(255,198,0,1)';
  this.setState({selected: true});
  this.props.goFunction(this.props.id);

}
    render() {
      const { id, searchName, matches } = this.props;

      const buttonStyle = {
        height: '100%',
        width: '93px',
        backgroundColor: '#FFC600'
      }

    return (
     <div style={this.state.panelStyle} className={this.isActive()}>
       <div class="col-xs-10">
       <div class="col-xs-7">
         Search Name: {searchName}
       </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
         Must Have: PHP, MySQL
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-7">
         Could Have: AngularJS
       </div>

       </div>

          <button type="button" onClick={this.viewNotifications.bind(this)} style={buttonStyle} class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> {matches} </button>



     </div>



    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think using `componentWillReceiveProps` to set the state from props is likely an anti-pattern in the same way as it is [doing in it in `getInitialState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)

Comment: Yeah as Proton mentioned above, actually there's no reason to update the current components state as the props get updated anyway! Thanks.